# Hiding Transform

Tags: 3d-view

The 'Transform' fly out will not go away and I don't know how to make it. I would have posted an image here but I don't see how. I have tried many things to fix such a simple problem.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: If you mean what I think you mean, Press N to toggle the object properties "fly out"

Comment: yep, that's the one. thank you very much. simple problem, simple solution, and simple user.